# Select rows where value between range and default to last row ID where value exceeded range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here's an example table

| ID | FROM | TO | MAX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100001 | 100.00 | 199.99 | 5 |
| 100002 | 200.00 | 299.99 | 4 |
| 100003 | 300.00 | 399.99 | 3 |
| 100004 | 400.00 | 499.99 | 2 |

This SQL works just fine. The result is row with row ID 10001.

```
DECLARE @VAL DECIMAL(6,2);
SET @VAL = 159.97
SELECT ID, FROM, TO, MAX   
FROM [MyTable].[dbo].[MagicPlan]
WHERE @VAL BETWEEN FROM AND TO;
```

But, I can't figure out how to default to the last row where @VAL exceeded the range. As it stands currently, changing @VAL to 695.43 returns no rows. I want it to return row ID 10004. Does that make sense?

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and won't get you help any faster. It's also quite rude to SHOUT at people you're asking for **free help** to solve **your problem**.

Comment: And if you provide your sample data as DDL+DML you make it much easier to assist.

Comment: What result would you want if two rows would qualify for the `WHERE`?

Comment: @KenWhite The uppercase is a DB2 for IBM I convention that I was forced to get used to in the past 2 years. We've recently modernized our legacy database so that it now accepts long table and column names, proper case. However, system names are still in uppercase and max 9 length. I have to keep my habits consistent in order to minimize errors in our environment.

Comment: I was talking about the title of your question, which you typed in ALL CAPS. I couldn't care less about your code conventions.

Comment: @KenWhite Well I'm confused because on my screen, title doesn't show up in all caps.

Comment: Because I edited it out. See the [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74215420/revisions)

Comment: Interesting. Seriously hadn't noticed it was in all caps. Thanks for editing it so it's less offensive to the eyes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TOP 1` and first order by your desired criteria, then order by your secondary criteria

```
DECLARE @VAL decimal(6,2) = 159.97;
SELECT TOP 1 ID, [FROM], [TO], [MAX]   
FROM [MyTable].[dbo].[MagicPlan]
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @VAL BETWEEN [FROM] AND [TO] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
    ID DESC;
```

Personally I would do it this way, because I find `BETWEEN` a bit unintuitive.

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, [FROM], [TO], [MAX]   
FROM [MyTable].[dbo].[MagicPlan]
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN [FROM] <= @VAL AND [TO] >= @VAL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
    ID DESC;
```

[DBFiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/Cq-EC2AI)

Comment: Dale, thanks for chiming in. I would've flagged yours as the solution and it does a nice job. Except when I tailor it to my real database and bump up @VAL to anything higher than 499.99 , it consistently brings back the row before the top 1 row which in the case of the sample table, row 100003. I'll play around with it some more to try and figure out why.

Comment: Post a DBFiddle and I'll take a look. It might be the functionality of `between` - personally I would never use it as its clearer to me to roll my own logic e.g. `column1 >= @Value and column1 < @Value

Comment: I see that DbFiddle doesn't support SQL server so, I choose MySQL v5.7 and had to replace TOP with LIMIT.  Here's the fiddle. It's strange, Your query works spot on but in my SQL server DB, it doesn't. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pj9WEL61mc2FJ61uUqBzLj/0

Comment: dbfiddle.uk works for SQL Server, you realise you missed the second part of my order by `, Id DESC`. Don't know if that makes the difference, but is [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Cq-EC2AI) working? Note I also added the way I would personally do it.

Comment: Yep your fiddle works and I see how leaving out the last part of the order by (id, desc), caused the shortcoming I saw on my end. Thanks for your help. I'll mark your answer as the solution.